# How to customize labels of a 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, labeling, customization, size

I need to change the label style on a 3D plot like this one below :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[4 t], Cos[4 t] + 1, t}, {t, -10, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 2}, {-2, 2}},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Boxed -> True,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.6],
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "a", Dot["a"]},
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", Medium],
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
    ImageSize -> {512, 512}
]
```

I don't want to change the ticks themselves and the numbers below them, only the labels (symbols) of each axes.  Currently, the labels are much too small and are on a wrong position (not clearly visible).  How can I displace them to the extremity of their axe, and make them bigger ?

This is certainly very standard and easy to do, so I searched the documentation but didn't found a clear and complete example yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to combine your `ParametricPlot` with `Text` using `Show`

You can precisely specify the location of your axes labels

```
Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[4 t], Cos[4 t] + 1, t}, {t, -10, 10}],

    Graphics3D@{
        Text[Style["t", Bold, Large, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 2, 0}],
        Text[Style["a", Bold, Large, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"], {-2, 0, 0}],
        Text[Style[OverDot["a"], Bold, Large, Purple, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 2}]},



    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
]
```

[image]

Comment: It appears to work great, thanks.  But I'm surprised there aren't some "simple" default commands to do this.

Comment: .     @Cham It is surprising. Usually including the option `AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Bold, Large, Green], 
  Style["y", Bold, Large, Red], Style["z", Blue, Large, Red]}` in the `ParametricPlot3D` works but I could not get it to place the labels at the ends of the Axes

Comment: maybe you would like `OverDot[ "a" ]` @Cham

Comment: Yep, thanks, I already fixed this one.  I'll mark your answer as the right one in a day or two, in case someone else find something nicer (I doubt it !).

Comment: Cheers! I would also be interested if someone could find a better way.

Comment: What if you have a Unicode text? it seems it renders the labels backward!